# How many Degrees of Freedom do Linear Triatomic Gas Molecules Have and Why?

Tags: ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, gas, degrees-of-freedom

I read this in one of my textbooks that stated

> Linear Triatomic Gas Molecules like CO2, HCN, CS2 in which all the atoms are linear, the total number of degrees of freedom are
>
> N<sub>f</sub> = N<sub>T</sub> + N<sub>R</sub> + N<sub>V</sub>
> where N<sub>T</sub>, N<sub>R</sub>, N<sub>V</sub> are the translational freedom, rotational freedom and vibrational freedom/s respectively.

Is this correct ? If yes then why do Linear Triatomic Gas Molecules have 7 degrees of freedom, If no then what will be the correct degree/s of freedom and why ?

Answer (score 0):

It is true not only for triatomic but for any molecule.

If your textbook is on thermal physics, then a linear triatomic molecule is said to have $3$(translational)$+2$(rotational)$+3*3-5$(vibrational)=$9$ d.o.f. For all vibrational modes to be active requires high temperatures. So normally at moderate temperatures, only $2$ vibrational modes are active. That's why people talk of $7$ d.o.f for a linear triatomic molecule.

Answer (score 0):

For a linear triatomic molecule, there are 3 degrees of freedom for each molecule, i.e., a total of $3N = 3 \times 3 = 9$ degrees of freedom. Since there are 2 constraints (say, bonds) between the 3 molecules, the total degrees of freedom are now $3N - 2 = 7$ degrees of freedom. Out of which 3 are translational, 2 are rotational, and the rest 2 is vibrational.